# Como converter numeros 2.15600e+03 (euler) para tipo numerico?

Tags: java

Estou com o seguinte problema: tenho que ler um arquivo que contém vários números muito grandes conforme exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao tentar ler eles e mandar pra uma variável double/long/int, da erro acusando que é uma *string*. Gostaria de saber como converter esse tipo de número em double/long/int (o que for aplicável neste caso).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a classe [Double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) para fazer a conversão:

Para [long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longValue%28%29):

```
long longVar = Double.valueOf("2.15600e+03").longValue();
```

Para [double](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleValue%28%29):

```
double doubleVar = Double.valueOf("2.15600e+03").doubleValue();
```